# PySpark - Append previous and next row to current row

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Let's say I have a PySpark data frame like so:

```
1 0 1 0
0 0 1 1
0 1 0 1
```

How can I append the last and next column of a row to the current row, like so:

```
1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
```

I'm familiar with the `.withColumn()` method for adding columns, but am not sure what I would put in this field.

The `"0 0 0 0"` are placeholder values because there are no prior or subsequent rows before and after those rows.

Comment: Can you make a more realistic example? Generally it's not a good idea to have `a`, `1` and `!` in one column, Same goes for other columns. With that said, `withColumn`, `lead` and `lag` should do what you need.

Comment: I'm sure you can imagine more realistic placeholders in my example. I just put them for ease of distinction.

Comment: Your example is confusing. Are `a, b, c, d` the column names? Where does `0 0 0 0` come from? See [how to create good reproducible apache spark dataframe examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-dataframe-examples) @Chris.

Comment: @pault Okay I'll change the example. The "0 0 0 0" are placeholder values because there are no prior or subsequent rows before and after those rows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`pyspark.sql.functions.lead()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.lead) and [`pyspark.sql.functions.lag()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.lag) but first  you need a way to order your rows. If you don't already have a column that determines the order, you can create one using [`pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id)

Then use this in conjunction with a `Window` function.

For example, if you had the following DataFrame `df`:

```
df.show()
#+---+---+---+---+
#|  a|  b|  c|  d|
#+---+---+---+---+
#|  1|  0|  1|  0|
#|  0|  0|  1|  1|
#|  0|  1|  0|  1|
#+---+---+---+---+
```

You could do:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

cols = df.columns
df = df.withColumn("id", f.monotonically_increasing_id())
df.select(
    "*", 
    *([f.lag(f.col(c),default=0).over(Window.orderBy("id")).alias("prev_"+c) for c in cols] + 
      [f.lead(f.col(c),default=0).over(Window.orderBy("id")).alias("next_"+c) for c in cols])
).drop("id").show()
#+---+---+---+---+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
#|  a|  b|  c|  d|prev_a|prev_b|prev_c|prev_d|next_a|next_b|next_c|next_d|
#+---+---+---+---+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
#|  1|  0|  1|  0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     1|     1|
#|  0|  0|  1|  1|     1|     0|     1|     0|     0|     1|     0|     1|
#|  0|  1|  0|  1|     0|     0|     1|     1|     0|     0|     0|     0|
#+---+---+---+---+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```